# Testing argument using Python Click

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, python-click

I have a command-line script with Python-click with an argument and option:

```py
# console.py
import click

@click.command()
@click.version_option()
@click.argument("filepath", type=click.Path(exists=True), default=".")
@click.option(
    "-m",
    "--max-size",
    type=int,
    help="Max size in megabytes.",
    default=20,
    show_default=True,
)
def main(filepath: str, max_size: int) -> None:
    max_size_bytes = max_size * 1024 * 1024  # convert to MB
    if filepath.endswith(".pdf"):
        print("success")
    else:
        print(max_size_bytes)
```

Both the argument and option have default values and work on the command-line and using the CLI it behaves as expected. But when I try testing it following Click [documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/arguments/) and debug it, it does not enter the first line:

```py
# test_console.py
from unittest.mock import Mock

import click.testing
import pytest
from pytest_mock import MockFixture

from pdf_split_tool import console

@pytest.fixture
def runner() -> click.testing.CliRunner:
    """Fixture for invoking command-line interfaces."""
    return click.testing.CliRunner()

@pytest.fixture
def mock_pdf_splitter_pdfsplitter(mocker: MockFixture) -> Mock:
    """Fixture for mocking pdf_splitter.PdfSplitter."""
    return mocker.patch("pdf_split_tool.pdf_splitter.PdfSplitter", autospec=True)

def test_main_uses_specified_filepath(
    runner: click.testing.CliRunner,
    mock_pdf_splitter_pdfsplitter: Mock, 
) -> None:
    """It uses the specified filepath."""
    result = runner.invoke(console.main, ["test.pdf"])
    assert result.exit_code == 0
```

I couldn't see why it is giving since the debugger did not enter the first line of function main(). Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: I've been using `click`'s testing package for a while, but it has caused me bugs and grief and I switched to invoking my entry points myself. You might want to do the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The failure is due to following error.

```
(pdb)print result.output
"Usage: main [OPTIONS] [FILEPATH]\nTry 'main --help' for help.\n\nError: Invalid value for '[FILEPATH]': Path 'test.pdf' does not exist.\n"
```

This is happening due to following code in console.py which checks if the filepath exists.
`@click.argument("filepath", type=click.Path(exists=True), default=".")`

One way to test creating a temporary file is using afterburner's code:

```py
# test_console.py
def test_main_uses_specified_filepath() -> None:
    runner = click.testing.CliRunner()
    with runner.isolated_filesystem():
        with open('test.pdf', 'w') as f:
            f.write('Hello World!')

        result = runner.invoke(main, ["test.pdf"])
    assert result.exit_code == 0
```

Comment: Thanks apoorva kamath! How can I see this error? afterburner just posted a test code as a complement to your answer. If you just could complete your answer with the code (since the bounty specified it needed code) I will mark as the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

I've changed your test method to the following. However, this is more an augmentation to apoorva kamath's answer.

```py
def test_main_uses_specified_filepath() -> None:
    runner = click.testing.CliRunner()
    with runner.isolated_filesystem():
        with open('test.pdf', 'w') as f:
            f.write('Hello World!')

        result = runner.invoke(main, ["test.pdf"])
    assert result.exit_code == 0
```

Simply put, it creates an isolated file system that gets cleaned up after the text is executed. So any files created there are destroyed with it.

For more information, [Click's Isolated Filesystem documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/testing/#file-system-isolation) might come in handy.

Alternatively, you can remove the `exists=True` parameter to your file path.

Comment: Thanks @afterburner. I think the answer is a merge of both your answers. Since apoorva kamath answered first I will give the right answer to her (and an upvote for you).

Comment: @staticdev appreciate it, and I approve, she's the one that figured it out

Comment: Just a minor improvement, `as f` and the `f.write` are not necessary to work. You can put the invoke in the place of `f.write` instead. =p

Comment: True. I wasn't sure if Python created an empty file if nothing was written to it, but today I learnt :D